# Unable to $pull from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have tried a lot of different ways but maybe I dont have the hang of the way mongodb needs me to query it.

this is what the doc looks like.

```
{
    "username" : "amitverma",
    "notifications" : {
        "notification_add_user" : [
            {
                "sender" : "a",
                "action" : "b",
                "type" : "c",
                "objectType" : "d",
                "objectUrl" : "e"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("539aa673e97933e7a5000001")
}
```

I want to remove the object inside "notification_add_user". And these are the different ways I have tried to get it working.

```
db.notifications.update(
    {'username': 'amitverma' },
    { $pull: {
         "notifications.notification_add_user":{'sender': "a"} 
    }}
)
```

This works in console.

But the code that I have written for it doesnt get the job done.

```
// notificationtype is 'add_user'
removequery['notifications.notification_' + notificationtype] = { 'sender': 'a' };

co_notifications.update(
    {'username': data.username},
    {$pull : removequery}, function(err, docs){
    console.log('remove notification callback')
    console.log(err)
    console.log(docs)
```

})
                            )

Comment: You might try logging your parameters and possibly `data.username` to see that you are getting what you expect. Also the second callback argument on `.update()` is the number of documents affected and not the document. If you want the document, try one of the "findBy/One" methods instead.

Comment: Unless  you pass the option `multi: true`, mongo will update the first document with `username: data.username` it finds. Could it be that there are multiple docs with that particular username?

Comment: No, only a single document.

Comment: Your code works when I try it.  What's not working about it for you?

Comment: it works in the mongodb console. doesn't work when i try to do it through a node function

Comment: Sure, but what specifically isn't working about your node code?  Do you get an error message?  Is it not matching any docs? etc.

Comment: it doesnt remove the subdocument that i want to remove.

Comment: Can you provide more complete code then?  What you've shown so far is correct.

Comment: which is the node.JS module you are using to interface with MongoDB ?? are you using the native driver 'mongodb' module ??

Answer (score 0):

Using the native `MongoDB` driver, I have used the following query to update from a node console and it works:

```
>MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
>format=require('util').format;

>MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('notifications');
      collection.count(function(err, count) {console.log(format("count = %s", count));});
      collection.update(
        {'username': 'amitverma'},
        {$pull:{'notifications.notification_add_user':{'sender':'a'}}},{w:1},function(err){
            if (err) console.warn(err.message);
            else console.log('successfully updated');
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.notifications.find({'username': 'amitverma' }).forEach( function(result) {
    var i;
    for(i in result.notifications.notification_add_user) {
        var sender = result.notifications.notification_add_user[i]['sender'];
        if(sender === 'a') {
            delete result.notifications.notification_add_user[i]['sender'];
        }
    }

    db.notifications.save(result);
});
```

1. First i will get all the results where the username is equal to
   'amitverma'
2. Then i loop through the notification_add_user array and see if sender is equal to 'a' and delete all the match results
3. And for last i save the changes